# Approximation of $\frac{e^{-\lambda |D|}(\lambda |D|)^k}{k!}$ when $|D|$ is very small

Tags: statistics, approximation, poisson-distribution

**EDITED: Sorry. I made a mistake, I think I want to ask why this approximation is valid when $|D|$ is very small, rather than how to find its limit when $|D| \to 0^+$; also, I made a typo, it should be $(\lambda|D|)^k$, not $(-\lambda|D|)^k$** .

I am currently learning poisson point process, and see the following statement in my lecture notes:

When $|D|$ is very small, 
$$\frac{e^{-\lambda |D|}(\lambda |D|)^k}{k!}$$
where $k$ is a non-negative integer and $\lambda$ is a positive constant

$= (1-\lambda |D|)$ for $k=0$,

$= \lambda |D|$ for $k=1$ and

$=o(|D|)$ (negligible) for $k=2,3,4,...$

It means a Poisson distributed random variable with parameter $\lambda|D|$ will approximately become Bernoulli distributed with parameter $\lambda|D|$ when $|D|$ is very small.

I know that a Bernoulli distribution (sum of Bernoulli trials) can be approximated by a Poisson distribution under certain circumstances ($n \to \infty$, $p \to 0$ and $np \to \theta$, $\theta$ is fixed and preferably $>5$), but I just can't figure out how the reversion works.

How can I get this approximate? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let
$f(x)
=\frac{e^{-cx}(-cx)^k}{k!}
$
where
$c > 0$
and $k$ is a positive integer.
(My notation is easier to use.)

We want to approximate $f(x)$
for small $x$.

For small $x$,
$e^{cx}
\approx 1+cx
$,
so
$f(x)
\approx \frac{(1-cx)(-cx)^k}{k!}
= \frac{(1-cx)(-cx)^k}{k!}
$,
so $f(x) \approx 1-cx$ if $k=0$
and
$f(x) = O(x^k)$
for $k \ge 1$.

Are you sure that
this is what you want,
because this isn't
very interesting.

Comment: Thanks. It is not so interesting, but I want to know why and how. Also, I made a typo, it should be $(\lambda|D|)^k$, not $(-\lambda|D|)^k$. And why it can be approximated by $\lambda|D|$ when $k=1$